# Basic CCArray understanding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Very new to C++ and Cocos2d-x but I was just toying around with CCArray and had a question. I'm used to NSMutableArray and NSArray, where i dont have to set the size for the array upon creation.

with CCArray every example i find of it has the size set

`CCArray *frames = CCArray::arrayWithCapacity(int)`

So my question is this, is it possible to leave the capacity open ended?
Is this gonna cause problems in the future? 
And can I add more elements in the future as I can do with NSMutableArray, but not NSArray.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cocos2d-x CCArray is mutable, i.e. you can add elements to it. To create CCArray instance without capacity, you can use `CCArray::array()` constructor. CCMutableArray is template-based container that can store objects of the same type. CCArray stores objects as CCObject instances, so you have to cast them after getting from CCArray instance